# how to remove a service that not be enabled after reboot?

Tags: 13.04, server

I want to remove unnecessary services in Ubuntu server 13.04 for hardening purpose.
I don't know use which blow command for dedicate services:
1. inintct list
2. sysv-rc-conf list
3. ls /etc/init.d
4. service --status-all

why outputs of each above command are different?
I tried stop atd service with "service atd stop", but after reboot system this
service start again.
Since I want hardening my server, how to disable a service permanently?
and which services should be disable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/init.d` holds the start up/shut down scripts for various services, but they are actually invoked by the scripts in `/etc/rc*.d`.

The `rc*.d` scripts are actually hold symbolic links to `/etc/init.d` scripts, and the names in the `rc*.d` directories say whether to start or stop a service as you enter that run level - the number in the name gives the order in which to run the scripts.

So, for example, `/etc/rc3.d/S23ntp` says to start the ntp daemon at run level 3 (after all the lower numbered services have been started).

So - to stop a service running after a reboot, the best thing to do is manipulate the `rc*.d` scripts.

And the best way to do that is to use the `update-rc.d` command. e.g. to disable ntp at boot, run:

```
update-rc.d ntp disable
```

As to what services to disable - be careful that you understand what a service does and its purpose before disabling it.

I was going to give `atd` as an example - this is a process that uses very little resource, but stopping it may have unintended consequences.

But as it turns out, `atd` is actually invoked by a different mechanism (`upstart`) - and I don't have time to go in to that now!

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend you to disable services you don't know of, to disable services that ship with the system you **have to have** deeper knowledge of the system. You could likely end up with a broken system.

Since it seems you do not know about [SysV-init](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) scripts or [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) jobs, i would suggest you get in touch with them first.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/ubuntu-startup-init-scripts-runlevels-upstart-jobs-explained).

Answer (score 0):

You can manage services on startup with rcconf:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

Then, start it:

```
sudo rcconf
```

And uncheck the ones you don't want loaded automatically on startup.